# convert a list of strings of ints to list of tuples

Tags: python, string, list

If I have a list that looks like this below of strings that are int values:

`['10 90', '10 -90', '100 45', '20 180']`

How would I convert it to a list of tuples? Like this:

`[(10,90), (10,-90), (100,45), (20,180)]`

This code below doesn't change the original list as I think lists in Python are mutable where I can change the values directly versus creating a new list of correct values. What's best approach?

```
newlines = []
for string in lines:
    newlines.append(tuple(string))
```

prints:

```
[('1', '0', ' ', '9', '0'), ('1', '0', ' ', '-', '9', '0'), ('1', '0', '0', ' ', '4', '5'), ('2', '0', ' ', '1', '8', '0')]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to split each string first. Then convert each split item to an integer; finally convert the pair to a tuple:

```py
out = [tuple(map(int, item.split())) for item in lst]
```

Output:

```
[(10, 90), (10, -90), (100, 45), (20, 180)]
```

Comment: Thanks ill hit the green check when I can. That creates a new list right?

Comment: @bbartling yes it does.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably do it with map and list comprehension, but for clarity's sake let's use simple loop:

```
values=['10 90', '10 -90', '100 45', '20 180']
result=[]
for x in values:
    pair=x.split()
    pair=tuple(map(int, pair))
    result.append(pair)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, should give you the same outcome, the old_lst is the list you want transformed. You should also get a similar result with item.partition(' ') but you would have to incorporate extra steps to pop out the space in the returned data.

```
old_lst = ['10 90', '10 -90', '100 45', '20 180']
new_lst = []

for item in old_lst:
    pair=item.split(' ')
    new_lst.append(tuple(pair))
```

Outcome:

```
[('10', '90'), ('10', '-90'), ('100', '45'), ('20', '180')]
```